# Android Studio Mac Os Catalina Gradle Permission Issues Unable to delete file:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, macos-catalina

After upgrading to Mac OS Catalina, Android Studio doesn't build, clean etc. It had stopped working.

When I try to clean project. I get warnings about delete files.

```
Unable to delete file: .../app/build/intermediates/proguard-files/proguard-android.txt-3.5.1
```

Here is what I tried.

- I switch to gradle path to global path from local gradlew file.
- I gave Full Disk Access permission to android studio and gradle.

Both solutions not working for me.

if I build apps from command line with command

```
sudo gradle assemble or sudo gradle clean
```

I'm able to build it but I cannot build with Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out. In project folder when right click on finder I clicked get info. In Sharing  & Permissions section I see everyone has assess only read only. I switch it to everyone and click settings icon below and say "Apply to enclosed items..." It's working now. It wasn't related to android studio permissions, It's related to project files...

Answer (score 0):

Changing permissions of the said folders to 777 might work.

`chmod 777 <filename>`

or

`chmod 777 <directory>`